# How to pass function in to a closure argument in swift 2.0

Tags: swift2, ios9, uialertaction

I am a beginner to IOS application development as well as swift.I am now trying to us UIAlertController.UIAlertAction asks me for three arguments.The third one is closure.What can i do if I want to pass my predefined function to this parameter?Here is my code.I have written func ask() before these codes.That function is also free from errors .But the following codes shows error named "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on declaring UIAlertAction.I am making the game toturial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/2/5/from-outlets-to-actions-ibaction-and-string-interpolation.

```
let a:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Your score is \(scores)", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let b:UIAlertAction=UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .Default, handler:ask)
        a.addAction(b)
        presentViewController(a, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you include your ask function?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct.  The error indicates that the types are not correct, however.  There is a good chances that your `ask` function does not have a method signature that matches the third parameter to the `title:style:handler` `init` method.  It needs to accept a parameter of type `UIAction` and return `Void`.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles recommended, you'd be best to provide your `ask` function, but most likely need to modify its arguments:

```
func ask(action: UIAlertAction!) {
...
}
```

and then also provide a `nil` argument when you call the `ask` function earlier in the `viewDidLoad` func.

```
ask(nil)
```

The tutorial author explains this in a bit more detail in the paragraph starting "Before the code completes"